# Import data from Tripadvisor to Google Spreadsheets or Excel

Tags: excel, web-scraping, import, tripadvisor

Is it possible to get a list of this data:
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g188590-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html

in Google Spreadsheets?

So, a list of all the restaurants in Amsterdam. And if possible with address details etc.

Please, let me know!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the result using python  in 2 ways

1. Using web scraping framework extract the data from your link and using pyexcel framework write the data to your excel file.

The below link explain in detail how to do web scraping using python
https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/

2. Using selenium and pyexcel

In case if the data need to be stored in Google sheet use gspread framework

Answer (score 0):

This is an example but with excel instead of Google Spreadsheets. It scrape only places names but you can easily scrape other informations and save it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

sheet1.write(0, 0, "Names")

url_1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g188590-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html'
sauce_1  = urllib.request.urlopen(url_1).read()
soup_1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce_1, 'lxml')

x = 1
for names in soup_1.find_all('div',class_='wQjYiB7z'):
    sheet1.write(x,0, names.text)
    x = x+1

book.save("trial.xls")
```